# How can I predict strong increases or decreases for a time series, e.g., by more than 25%?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, forecasting, predictive-models

I have a time series. I would like to have a model that takes in past and current values and outputs something like a probability / number that tells me:

- If the value is going up by more than 25%
- If the value is going down by more than 25%
- Neither of the above

I wanted to try Neural Networks (Not interested in LSTMs), but are there other techniques? If not, do you know of a good resource?

Comment: Often machine learning does not work well with time-series data and the classical time-series (ARIMA etc.) models work much better.

Answer (score 4):

Any forecasting method that outputs *predictive densities* (also known as *density forecasts*, i.e., density functions giving the predicted distribution of the next observation) would address your needs. (Note that these are related to a [prediction-interval](/questions/tagged/prediction-interval), which in turn is *not* the same as a [confidence-interval](/questions/tagged/confidence-interval), a common confusion.)

Suppose the last observation was $y$, and the predictive density for the next observation is $\hat{F}$. Then the probability that the next value will be 25% lower is $\hat{F}(0.75y)$, the probability that it will be 25% higher will be $1-\hat{F}(1.25y)$, and the probability for "none of the above" will be $\hat{F}(1.25y)-\hat{F}(0.75y)$.

You don't say what kind of time series you have (continuous, discrete, [intermittent-time-series](/questions/tagged/intermittent-time-series), lumpy), but of course you should use a forecasting method that is appropriate for your series.

For instance, here is an illustration using `ets()` in the `forecast` package. This is not a use case that `forecast.ets()` was built for, so the output is a little painful to parse.

```
# library(forecast)
# model <- ets(AirPassengers)
# pred <- forecast(model,h=1,level=51:99,simulate=TRUE)
# tail(AirPassengers,1)
[1] 432
# pred
         Point Forecast    Lo 51    Hi 51    Lo 52    Hi 52    Lo 53    Hi 53
Jan 1961       441.7166 430.5646 452.6473 430.1879 452.9241 429.9727 453.1164
            Lo 54    Hi 54    Lo 55   Hi 55   Lo 56    Hi 56    Lo 57    Hi 57
Jan 1961 429.6617 453.4028 429.3353 453.696 429.021 454.0116 428.6747 454.2898
            Lo 58    Hi 58    Lo 59    Hi 59    Lo 60    Hi 60   Lo 61   Hi 61
...
```

The last observation was 432. Taking somewhat narrower intervals (because the forecasts simply don't envisage sudden declines or increases by 25%), and looking at the output, we see that $0.95\times 432=410.4$ corresponds roughly to the "Lo 95" entry, while $1.05\times 432=453.6$ corresponds roughly to the "Hi 55" entry. Thus, there seems to be a roughly 5% chance of a decline by 5% or more, and a 45% chance of an increase by 5% or more. The asymmetry is not surprising, given the trend and seasonality.

Answer (score 4):

In general you can perform forecasting with any classification method by:

- creating a class variable that describes what you want to be able to predict (in your example this could be a nominal variable with three values: falling, stable and rising)
- adding lagged copies of the existing predictors to your dataset.

For example if you wanted to predict crop yields from temperature and rainfall data you would add a predictor for **last month's** temperature and rainfall, **last year's** temperature and rainfall, and so on, just by copying the existing data and shifting it by the selected amount. Clearly you have to choose and/or experiment with the number and time shift of the lagged predictors that you are going to use, and the normal principles of predictor number versus data size and requirement to validate your model continue to apply.

Packages such as Weka include tools for forecasting by creating lagged copies of predictors.